# Is it possible to change my MAC address?

Tags: networking, mac-address

The wikipedia article on MAC address mentions that it is stored in the ROM of the NIC. How can the MAC address be changed then?

Comment: Actually this does not specify if what you want to do this from a windows based computer, however my 2nd source provides instruction for *nix based systems

Comment: (Just in case you think that, for example, web sites you visit can see your MAC address: they don't.)

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. I wanted to know how is it possible to change the MAC address and not the actual procedure.

Comment: Well, @Manish, you kind of fooled all of us with that title... ;-)

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/a/49884/78897

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The physical MAC address is hardware dependent and is stored on the NIC's ROM (EEPROM) chip. To physically change this you would have to do what is known as flashing the ROM chip on the NIC.

You can however do what is know as "spoofing" which is tricking the operating system to think that it is actually different. It can be done within the registry or using 3rd party [software](http://www.technitium.com/tmac/index.html).

Sources:

- Personal Experience
- [Changing Your
  MAC Address](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Changing_Your_MAC_Address)

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/a/875286/78897

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to change my MAC
>   address?

in a word, yes.

Here's a tutorial for Windows:

**[Change MAC Address or Physical Address Using Registry Editor (regedit) in Windows](http://www.techrena.net/computers/change-mac-address-physical-address-registry-editor-regedit-windows/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quite easily in Windows for most if not all network cards.

1. Right click on computer->manage
2. Select device manager double click on your network card
3. Select the advanced tab
4. Select Network Address and enter the MAC address you want to use

This can be usable in situations where your ISP has "locked" your connection to a certain MAC address and not assigning any IP address. It's also found in most home routers on the market for this situation.

Comment: this doesn't work for all network adapters, the registry method does.

Comment: @Molly, I wonder if the Registry indeed works for all network adapters? I would *expect* (but I am no expert) that the adapter's driver must provide some means to change it. If it doesn't: no luck with *any* method. If it does, then why wouldn't Windows provide an input field in its device manager?

Comment: The visual version of this answer is at http://superuser.com/a/875178/78897

Answer (score 1):

It is operating system dependent, but there are built in mechanisms in Linux to do this and easily used third party tools to do it in Windows.

It is possible, because that address is included in packets that are sent out through the TCP/IP stack, the software will spoof the address in the stack before they leave the host.

If you post your OS, you can get an exact answer on how to do it.

Comment: `regedit.exe` is not a "third party tool", is it?