# Giving my PC the same MAC address of my Android phone

Tags: wireless-networking, mac

I want my PC to replace my Android phone in a local wireless network from MAC Address point of view. In other words changing my PC’s MAC address to be exactly the same as the MAC address of my Android phone.

I could not perform this even when I change the PC MAC address manually using Regedit by creating and setting `NetworkAddress` entry in the related driver. It seems to me that the operating system refuses the new MAC value (first two digit) written in the registry and go back to network adapter ROM and re-read the original MAC during the adapter reboot; adapter disabling and re-enabling.

- How could somebody explain that?
- Does somebody have any suggestion to resolve the original issue: Replacing the phone by PC in getting in to the network.

**NOTE:** Of course I am not trying to make them connect together to the network.

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I change the MAC address of my PC?

> **Windows**
>
> Most network cards will allow you to set a custom MAC address from
> their configuration panes in the Device Manager, although **some network
> drivers may not support this feature**.
>
> First, open the Device Manager.
>
> - On Windows 8.1, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
>   and click "Device Manager".
> - On Windows 7, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type
>   “Device Manager” to search for it, and click "Device Manager".
>
> Locate the network interface you want to modify under Network
> Adapters, right-click it, and select "Properties".
>
> [image]
>
> Click the "Advanced" tab and select "Network Address" in the list. Your
> network driver doesn’t support this feature if the option isn’t here.
>
> Enable the "Value" option and enter your desired MAC address without any
> separating characters — don’t use dashes or colons. Click "OK"
> afterwards.
>
> [image]
>
> To apply the changes, either reboot your computer or device, or disable and re-enable the network adapter from Windows.

Source [How (and Why) to Change Your MAC Address on Windows, Linux, and Mac](http://www.howtogeek.com/192173/how-and-why-to-change-your-mac-address-on-windows-linux-and-mac/)

Comment: @PärBjörklund, I don't see it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dC3qZ.png

Comment: @Pacerier Locally Administered MAC address -> Network Address?

Comment: Oh yea..... Is your default also the case whereby "Not present" is selected? Or is the Value written in the Value box?

Comment: In my case "not present" is selected and the "value" box is empty. If I select the "value" box I can enter a mac address (without hyphens).

Answer (score 1):

If the above solutions, which depends on your driver supporting Mac spoofing, does not work, you can always go the software route to spoof a mac.

There are a number of tools that can do it in Windows but I think that smac is the easiest to do it short term, without tons of rebooting your system.

Here's a link if you want to try the software route.

http://m.download.cnet.com/SMAC-MAC-Address-Changer/3000-2085_4-10536535.html

Comment: I know how to change the MAC address using device manager or using software like SMAC or even by perform it manually using regedit, the problem is not there. My problem that I have tried to change my PC’s MAC to be exactly the same as the MAC address of my Samsung Android phone, the MAC changer software did not accept the first two digit ( it was : 18) and asked me to change them. Even when I did it manually by using Regedit; creating and setting NetworkAddress entry in the related driver, it did not work. It seems to me that the OS refuses the new MAC value written in the registry.

Comment: Maybe somebody asks why want to perform this replacement. The answer is simple; the network I deal with applies a MAC filter, it is forbidden for my PC and NOT for my phone.