# Changed MAC address of Wireless card being ignored?

Tags: windows-7, mac-address

I am attempting to spoof a MAC address on my wireless card (Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205) in Windows 7.

Since the Driver Properties dialog doesn't have an option to change the address, I've had to dive into the registry. In there I've already changed the proper key to get a Network Address, which for me is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0015\NetworkAddress`. Other programs like TMAC seem to just be nicer ways to change this value.

This value has been set and Windows has already been rebooted. However my MAC address has not changed. I've even changed the virtual Wi-Fi network card's address thinking it might help, but nothing happened.

Are there any other ways to change my wireless card's MAC address? Or is this just one of those wireless cards that can't be changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download Intel's Wireless ProSet and install it (with advanced options).  This will give you all the configuration options possible, and MAC spoofing is usually one of them (can't say for sure for [your specific WiFi model](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/centrino-advanced-n-6205.html)).

Intel Wireless ProSet direct download links (from Intel's support pages): [32-bit](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?ProductID=3316&DwnldID=20442&lang=eng&iid=dc_rss) - [64-bit](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?ProductID=3316&DwnldID=20443&lang=eng&iid=dc_rss)

Grab the larger package for your bit-level, as it will include the ProSet utility instead of just the driver.

Also see: [How do I change the MAC address of my network card?](https://superuser.com/questions/49883/how-do-i-change-the-mac-address-of-my-network-card)

Answer (score 3):

Actually Intel prevents such practice: https://web.archive.org/web/20150510203930/http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-031081.htm

Comment: Well that's interesting. Makes you wonder what caused them to start actively prevent spoofing

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're on the right way, just make sure the MAC Address you insert in the registry starts with 12.. Then add 10 more 16bit digits. Disable and re-enable your network adapter afterwards. It would most likely work then. In case you still have problems follow this guide..:
http://snaked-bytes.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-change-your-mac-address-in.html

Comment: Could you please post the contents of the guide here as opposed to just linking?\

Comment: Any success with this recently? Does not seem to work anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Intel® Centrino® Wi-Fi Products
How can I change the MAC address for my wireless adapter?

The Media Access Control (MAC) address is hard-coded on Intel® wireless adapters and cannot be changed.

Some third-party software applications can "spoof" a MAC address to a different address, but for security reasons, Intel does not support this practice.

Beginning with 12.x wireless driver package, the possibility of "spoofing" the MAC address was blocked to prevent this practice.

Source Link: http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-031081.htm

Comment: Source link? This directly contradicts what techie007 said

Comment: i tried changing my intel n-130's MAC using SMAC2.0 and it didn't take effect. I have updated the answer with source link.